# How many dots can be purchased at a time during advancement?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, character-advancement, vampire-the-requiem-2e

Is there any limitation on how many dots can be purchased at a time? e.g. one attribute dot per advancement, perhaps?  I saw this somewhere on the inter-webs, but cannot find the post again, so I don't know if that was a house-rule or a reference to the standard rules.

I request that answers reference page numbers or other sources if at all possible.  I have access to both the GMC rules update document and the V:tR 2nd Edition core rules, both of which are fairly sparse in their advice on experience and advancement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no rule that imposes a hard limit on the amount of experiences that you can use in a single session. The only related reference that I can find is in the original World of Darkness corebook, p. 217:

*It takes time and study to learn new things. If a character does not already possess some basic competence in a Skill, he must spend time training in it before any dots can be
purchased. The Storyteller decides just what he needs to do to qualify.*

So in essence, you can spend as much as the Storyteller allows, whenever he allows you to do so, as long as it makes sense in the story.

Comment: I upvoted because your answer is certainly relevant to the question.  However, I also wish to note that I'm looking for a specifically 2e/GMC solution.  I am sure you were aware of this and only cited the WoD core rules because the 2e and GMC rules were so sparse on info.

Comment: I would also invite you to weigh in on my other, related question: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62627/when-do-characters-advance

Comment: 2e/GMC only contains upgrades for some rules. Everything that is not explicitly updated by GMC is still valid from the original corebook. This is explained in GMC p 150.

Comment: @user1234567890 maybe you want for the wod 2nd edition core book there but else there has been no change in 2nd edition to the stated excerpt. The only thing that is indeed different is how many experience points you need to buy things.